# Cast object from derived to base and than back

Tags: c++, oop, casting

If i cast an object to the base type and store it in a std::map, and then get it back and recast it to the derived type, do i still have the correct data in the derived class members ?

Do i need to make a specific kind of cast ?

Comment: sepp2k's answer covers how to keep the data. For the casts `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` are available as well as the usual C style casting.

Comment: Also note that downcasting is "often" a code smell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're casting pointers to the object, it's no problem because the pointers will still point to the same object.

If you're casting the actual object, all information from the subclass will be lost when its converted to the superclass, so casting it back won't restore that information.

Comment: Casting the actual object? How? Use `static_cast`?

Comment: @Alcott Yes, or C-style casts or simply using the copy constructor or assignment operator, i.e. `SuperClass obj(SubClass());` or `obj = SubClass();` (though technically that might not count as a cast).