# Casting float to int pointer and back to float?

Tags: c, pointers, types

Can some explain me the behavior of this C program I was trying to understand its behavior...

```
#include<stdio.h>
float x = 3.33,*y,z;
int *a,b;
int main() {
    a = (int *)&x;
    b = (int)x;
    y = (float *)a;
    z = (float)b;
    printf("\nOriginal Value of X: %f \ncasting via pointer A:%d and back Y: %f \ndirect casting B:%d and back Z:%f\n",x,*a,*y,b,z);
}
```

Output:

```
Original Value of X: 3.330000                                                                                                                                                   

casting via pointer A:1079320248 and back Y: 3.330000                                                                                                                           

direct casting B:3 and back Z:3.000000
```

OK so why is the value of `A` is `1079320248` and its not some random value its always the same for `X = 3.33` and it changes if `X` is changed to some different value I was expecting something like `A` to be `3` but its not.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be a random value?

Comment: C++ is not C, please don't tag C++

Comment: Trying to reason about undefined behavior is not very productive.

Comment: [This web page](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) will let you play around with IEEE floating point.

Comment: maybe its undefined may be not but being a beginner I am just trying to understand C...

Comment: *maybe its undefined may be not*, it certainly is. It worked fine on your system. On other systems you might not get the results you expect.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya is very correct. I've tried to clarify the "why" part in a bit detail in my answer.

Comment: There is nothing meaningful to be learnt from studying this code. Move on and forget about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'casting via pointer A' happening in your code. You are just forcing the compiler to point `a` to a float value, where it is assumed to be pointing to an integer.

Using the [page](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) pointed out by Reymond Chen in the comment section, we get the binary representation of 3.33 as:

`01000000010101010001111010111000`

Now, use [this](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?hexadecimal=40551EB8) page to find its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. You'll get `1079320248`, which is the exact non-random number that puzzles you.

If this doesn't make any sense to you, let me make it much clearer. Both `a` and `y` are pointing to the same binary value `01000000010101010001111010111000`, which represents two different values (3.33 as float and 1079320248 as int) depending on the data type you tell the compiler to use for it.

**Update:**

Just for academic interest, if you want the printf statement to print 3 for `A`, replace the third parameter with this:

`(int) *((float *)a)`

Comment: [http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?hexadecimal=40551EB8](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?hexadecimal=40551EB8) explained everything thx!!

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** Casting a pointer to a different non-compatible type and back and then accessing the last one is OK, the problem starts when you try to use the intermediate pointer with non-compatible type.

---

To elaborate, your code causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you violate strict aliasing rule.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:<sup>88)</sup>
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>   object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the
>   effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type.

So in your case, for a definition like

```
 float x = 3.33,*y,z;
 //....
  a = (int *)&x;
  b = (int)x;
  y = (float *)a;
```

You are first casting a pointer to `float` to an integer pointer and then, casting it back to `float *` and according to the rule mentioned in chapter §6.3.2.3/P7

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
>   resulting pointer is not correctly aligned <sup>68)</sup> for the referenced type, the behavior is
>   undefined. **Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the
>   original pointer.** [...]

So, accessing `y` is fine, but not `a`. You will face alignment mismatch, which leads to UB. Don't try to do that. Respect the types.

Comment: Thx for such an explanation and it explained the UB of the program but that thing that led me for such a program was  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261405/cast-object-from-derived-to-base-and-than-back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261405/cast-object-from-derived-to-base-and-than-back) I know both `int` and `float` aren't base or derived but I was just trying what happens out of curiosity..

Comment: @livzz First of all, __C__ `!=` __C++__ `!=` __C__, They are different languages and demand to be treated as such. :) Choose one and stick to that please. That said, once UB, forever UB, you cannot have any meaningful output from it.

Comment: *Casting a pointer to a different non-compatible type and back and then accessing the last one is OK*  I'd think not - pointers to non-compatible types don't have to be the same size...