# C language - Pointers and Cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I know how pointers work, but I'm having some trouble understanding this cast with pointers.

```c
float f;
scanf("%f", &f);
unsigned int x = *(unsigned int*)&f;
```

Can someone explain me how this works?

Comment: Strictly speaking it breaks strict aliasing and invokes *undefined behavior* - which means it doesn't work

Comment: The code is invalid. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512402/casting-float-to-int-pointer-and-back-to-float

Comment: @SaymoinSam that is incorrect, `unsigned int x = (unsigned int)f` does something completely different (namely it casts the floating point number and truncates). The pointer cast would reinterpret the bytes of the floating point number as an unsigned integer

Comment: Sorry my bad...

Answer (score 7):

```
unsigned int x = *(unsigned int*)&f;
```

basically means "take the address of `f`, pretend it's an address to an `unsigned int` instead of a `float`, and dereference the result.

It's basically attempting to copy the bits from `f` into `x` without any type conversion.

As mentioned in the comments, this breaks a rule known as the "[strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)", and the behavior on doing so is *undefined*.  This *may* work as expected.  It may not.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to @John Bode's answer, try (and maybe debug) the following code to make things clear.

It's like, looking at the same bit pattern;

1. wearing a `float` set of eyeglasses,
2. wearing an `int` set of eyeglasses.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printBits(int k) {
    char bitStr[33];

    // put a string terminator at end of string
    bitStr[32] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        if (k & 1) {
            bitStr[31 - i] = '1'; // if 32nd bit is 1
        }
        else {
            bitStr[31 - i] = '0'; // if 32nd bit is 0
        }

        k = k >> 1; // shift all bits 1 bit right, dropping the right most (32nd) bit
    }

    printf("%s", bitStr);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    float f = 1.0f;
    int i = *(int *)&f;

    printf("bit pattern ");
    printBits(*(int *)&f);
    printf(" equals to %f in float\n", f);

    printf("bit pattern ");
    printBits(i);
    printf(" equals to %d in integer\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```